# How to use logical formula to return a TRUE value

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

I need help to use a formula in excel to help me get the list of names to be followed up in my tele-call report. Only Parameters with Contact Not Reachable, Contact Not Available, Contact Not Sure / Undecided need to be followed up and the rest (Not Interested - No Representative, Appointment Confirmed, Blocked by Gatekeeper are NOT required any follow up.

I've tried using OR to get a return of FALSE for names need not to be followed up with above parameters mentioned but failed when i get a TRUE showing combination of  Contact Not Reachable and Not Interested - No Representative in the next column.

Answer (score 0):

Hope, my understanding is right. Please refer the snap below

Apply the below formula in E2 and drag down

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Contact Not Reachable"),COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Contact Not Sure / Undecided"),COUNTIF(B2:D2,"Contact Not Available"))>=1,"Follow Up", "No Need")
```

[image]

Comment: =IF(SUM(COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact Not Reachable"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact Not Sure / Undecided"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact Not Available"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact Potentially Attending / Maybe"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact will Reply to Invitation"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Not Interested - Sending Representative"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Outstation / Overseas Number"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Requested to Call Back"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Requested to Resend Invitation / Email"))>=1,"Follow Up", "No Need")

Comment: Thanks Karthick, I've tried your formula but it give me Follow Up Contact Not Reachable Not Interested - No Representative 
Follow Up Contact Not Reachable Appointment Confirmed 
Follow Up Contact Not Reachable Contact Not Available Blocked by Gatekeeper
Follow Up Contact Not Available Contact Not Sure / Undecided Contact Not Reachable
Follow Up Contact Not Reachable Appointment Confirmed Contact Not Reachable
Follow Up Contact Not Reachable Contact Not Reachable Blocked by Gatekeeper
Follow Up Contact Not Reachable Contact Not Sure / Undecided Contact No Longer with the Company

Comment: Sorry I cant upload the screen shot of the excel

Comment: can you please post your excel? so that it will be easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8RHk.jpg)

I've edited your formula with the below:
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact Not Reachable"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact Not Sure / Undecided"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact Not Available"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact Potentially Attending / Maybe"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Contact will Reply to Invitation"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Not Interested - Sending Representative"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Outstation / Overseas Number"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Requested to Call Back"),COUNTIF(AP:AU,"Requested to Resend Invitation / Email"))>=1,"Follow Up", "No Need")